# Why I get error "This service requires an API key"?

Tags: php, google-places

I am trying to send post request to Google places API using the following PHP code but I get error

> string(141) "{ "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
>   "html_attributions" : [], "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
>   } "

```
<?php
include_once 'configuration.php';

$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json';
$data = array('query' => 'restaurants in Sydney', 'key' => API_KEY);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Ensure you are passing the API key correctly as they want it.

Comment: Please invalidate your key and use new one. By sharing your key in the post will has a risk of request theft and drain your request quota (and will probably charge you a lot of money).

Comment: yes will change thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation of  text search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests), the parameter need to be in GET method. You supplied it as POST.

```
A Text Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/output?parameters

...

Certain parameters are required to initiate a search request. As is standard in URLs, all parameters are separated using the ampersand (&) character.
```

Try this snippet instead:

```
<?php
include_once 'configuration.php';

$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' . urlencode('restaurants in Sydney') . '&key=' . API_KEY;

$result = file_get_contents($url);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

To make use of the array parameter, change `$url` to:

```
$data = array('query' => 'restaurants in Sydney', 'key' => API_KEY);
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?' . http_build_query($data);
```

Comment: But I saw in example 2 they use this form here
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: thanks but if possible please advise how to do it using arrays like in my code

Comment: thanks but I get new error now so better I will make a new post